# Redesign TabControl Menu c# (New colors, no borders)

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

The basic TabControl doesn't fit my needs design wise and needed a redesign.
The things that i needed were:

- No borders
- Gray background with white text for the selected tab
- Black background with gray text for not selected tab
- No doted line inside the selected tab (this one is a bit low priority)

I managed to fix some of these issues by creating a new class except for the last two. Seeing my limited experience (first time doing something like this) I was hoping somebody here could point me in the right direction.

Below an illustration of what it currently is and how I would want it to look. And of course the code of the class I used to do this.

What it looks  like:

[image: What it looks like]

What i want it to look like:

[image: What I want it to look like]

The code:

```
class CustomTabControl : TabControl
{
    public CustomTabControl(): base()
    {
        this.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);
    }

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

        Font fntTab;
        Brush bshBack;
        Brush bshFore;            
        
        if (e.Index == this.SelectedIndex)
        {            
            fntTab = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            bshBack = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.FromArgb(64,64,64), Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
            bshFore = Brushes.White;                
        }
        else
        {
            fntTab = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            bshBack = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.FromArgb(0,0,0), Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
            bshFore = Brushes.Gray;
        }                

        string tabName = this.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
        StringFormat sftTab = new StringFormat();
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, e.Bounds);
        Rectangle recTab = e.Bounds;
        recTab = new Rectangle(recTab.X +3 , recTab.Y+3, recTab.Width, recTab.Height );
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabName, fntTab, bshFore, recTab, sftTab);

        Rectangle r = this.GetTabRect(this.TabPages.Count - 1);
        RectangleF tf = new RectangleF(r.X + r.Width, r.Y - 2, this.Width - (r.X + r.Width) + 0, r.Height + 4);
        Brush b = Brushes.Black;

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, tf);
    }
    
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0005) 
        {
            int Width = unchecked((short)m.LParam);
            int Height = unchecked((short)((uint)m.LParam >> 16));

            Region = new Region(new Rectangle(4, 2, Width - 8, Height - 6));
        }
        
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }      
}
```

(And suggestions on improving this class are welcome.)

Comment: It's not worth trying to extend the built-in controls; it's better to use 3rd party controls. You can get a free "community" license for Syncfusion that includes their Winforms package. 

https://www.syncfusion.com/winforms-ui-controls/tabcontrol (that's the control you can use)
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense (link to get free license).

Other paid options are:
https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/ (my preferred choice)
https://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx